# Scala 2.7 will work with JDK 7? Stanford topic modelling toolkit?

Tags: scala, topic-modeling

I'm compiling a scala version `2.7` program from terminal

i'm using [stanford's topic modelling toolkit](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tmt/tmt-0.4/) library which only works on that version

This is the program

```
import scalanlp.io._

object Stanfordtmt {

    def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val pubmed = CSVFile("pubmed-oa-subset.csv");
    println("Success: " + pubmed + " contains " + pubmed.data.size + " records");


  }
}
```

I'm compiling using this command

`scalac -classpath "tmt-0.4.0.jar" Stanfordtmt.scala`

This is the error i get.

I wonder if this is because scala 2.7 is not compatible with open openjdk-7? Or could it be something else?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: List(object Byte, object Byte)
    at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:92)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Symbols$Symbol.suchThat(Symbols.scala:821)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Symbols$Symbol.linkedModuleOfClass(Symbols.scala:972)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Symbols$Symbol.linkedClassOfClass(Symbols.scala:988)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Definitions$definitions$.addModuleMethod$1(Definitions.scala:587)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Definitions$definitions$.initValueClasses(Definitions.scala:590)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Definitions$definitions$.init(Definitions.scala:726)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.<init>(Global.scala:476)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Main$.process(Main.scala:72)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Main$.main(Main.scala:87)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Main.main(Main.scala)
```

Answer (score 1):

Run the program like this

`java -jar tmt-0.4.0.jar Stanfordtmt.scala`

Personally, i use the `0.2.1` version because this latest version is buggy for large input files